# Using route into js foreach loop

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have this code

```
data.forEach(element => {

  dataHtml += `<a href="{{ route('pl.frontend.article.single', ['id' => '']) }}/` +element.id+ `"><figurestyle="background-image: url(/uploads/article/` +element.cover+ `)"> </figure></a></li>`;
});
```

It doesn't work becouse Laravel display an error that this route required parameters

> Missing required parameters

Why it doesn't work? How can I solve my problem?

Comment: `['id' => '']` `id` should not be blank

Answer (score 0):

I think if you'll modify code like following, it will work!

```
data.forEach(element => {
  dataHtml += `<a href="{{ route('pl.frontend.article.single'," + `element.id` + "}}"><figurestyle="background-image: url(/uploads/article/` +element.cover+ `)"> </figure></a></li>`;
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work but I found how I can do that. http://constituteweb.com/javascript-variable-in-laravel-route. But I can't use this same method in order to replace lang, Currently I have `pl.frontend...`. Pl should by change depending on which language is choosen. Language is in $lang var.